# Angular Material UI - autocomplete to initially keep the existing form field value

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Reactive Forms feature from Angular Material UI to display some existing data. Within this data set I have a form field called "country" which is prepopulated with value when page is loaded. Everything is fine to this end.

```
<mat-form-field class="app-table-full-width">
    <input matInput formControlName="country" placeholder="Country" value="{{ dealer.country }}">
</mat-form-field>
```

I would like to implement auto completion feature on the "country" field however, I'm unable to keep the existing Country value which appears to show empty field.

These are the changes I made;

```
<mat-form-field class="app-table-full-width">
  <input
    type="text"
    matInput
    formControlName="country"
    placeholder="Country"
    [matAutocomplete]="auto"
    >
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayCountry">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredCountryOptions | async" [value]="option">
      {{ option.name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Component code additions;

```
countryList: Array<ICountry> = [];
filteredCountryOptions: Observable<ICountry[]>;

ngOnInit() {
...
  this.filteredCountryOptions = this.dealerForm.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
      map(name => name ? this._filter(name) : this.countryList.slice())
    );
}

displayCountry(subject): string {
  return subject ? subject.name : '';
}
```

Comment: Angular material already provides an autocomplete component if that is what you want. https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

Comment: @YoniAffuta It does indeed and you can see from the code snippet I shared above that I'm using it already.

Comment: My bad i missed that. I also had troubles with that and then i moved to using ng-select autocomplete component with material theme to get an easier implementation.  https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select.